# Displaying text and variable in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am trying to display a specific 'string' in a PHP array on a wordpress system.

I have a declared a variable `$current_user->ID,` that returns the current user e.g. "Admin"

I would now like to try and combine this with normal text in an array to make the text dynamic.

In plain English, I am trying to create something that will display as follows:

*Post by: current_user*

This is the array I have:

```
'post_title'        =>  'Posted By:' . $current_user->ID .'',
```

but I know that what I have is not correct. The problem lies with connecting the plain text and the variable along with the quote marks.

Can anyone help?

UPDATE - MORE OF CODE:

```
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'open',
        'ping_status'       =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $current_user->ID,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  'Posted By:' . $current_user->ID'',
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post',
        'post_content'      =>  $_POST['quick-post-area']
    )
);
```

Comment: which is the error returned ?

Comment: Shwo a little more of the coed. That on its own is useless

Comment: This is the error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '''' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: @RiggsFolly please see updated question

Comment: In the code you have missing the dot before last ''

Comment: Remove the pair of single-quotes at the end of this line: `        'post_title'        =>  'Posted By:' . $current_user->ID'',
`